# Android SQLight encryption best lightweight option?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlcipher-android

I need to encrypt some of the data stored in my Android SQLite database, and I wonder what my options are if i want a lightweight option? Is SQLCipher still the best if speed is priority?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, [SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) is still an optimal solution. It provides AES 256 bit encryption which is pretty good.